# Python DataFrame: Adding Prediction Column to Pandas Dataframe from Linear Regression Model

Tags: python, pandas, output, regression, statsmodels

I have a data frame with three columns:

```
ID  Input_Var   Actual_Value
1   234         123
2   54          43
3   2           52
4   4           3
5   6           1
```

I have created a linear regression model with the code below:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = df_adhoc_1_final["MIN_SPAN"] ## X usually means our input variables (or independent variables)
y = df_adhoc_1_final["SPAN_DAYS"] ## Y usually means our output/dependent variable
X = sm.add_constant(X) ## let's add an intercept (beta_0) to our model

# Note the difference in argument order
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit() ## sm.OLS(output, input)
predictions = model.predict(X)
```

I want to add the predictions as a new column in my existing data frame.  Please see desired table below:

```
ID  Input_Var   Actual_Value    Predictions
1   234         123             211
2   54          43              58
3   2           52              49
4   4           3               3.4
5   6           1               5
```

To achieve the above, I used the following code:

```
df_adhoc_1_final['predictions'] = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
```

Is the above the correct code?  Is it aligning the predictions with the right rows?

Comment: *Is the above the correct code?* If it renders your desired results, then yes!

Comment: If you set an index on `ID` before the OLS, you'll get back an indexed result after the `fit()` method.  Try it, then when you add it back to the frame, it will implicitly align on your index.

Comment: thx, how do I set an index on ID?

Comment: This question is really bad. `MIN_SPAN` and `SPAN_DAYS` is not even in your sample data. Second, you're just asking how to add a column to an existing dataframe?